# How to specify the node version for rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I changed the node version in one rails app, which I believe changed the node version globally (i.e. for the whole of my laptop), which isn't desirable (I prefer to keep different apps on different node versions until they're ready to be upgraded).

Can I set the node version on a *per app* basis somehow?

E.g. analogously to how we can specifiy a ruby version on a per-app basis by creating a file called `.ruby-version` with the version number in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can install nvm, and then place a `.nvmrc` file containing the version number in the root of your project.

Installing via

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

will attempt to add the initializer to your appropriate shell configuration.

See https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating for installation options.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I'm trying to achieve. Do you know if the file can be simply created by hand? (i.e. without running a remote script)?

Comment: Sure, you can download the nvm repo and run the install script after you inspect the source. I forgot to include a link to the repo; I've added it above.

Comment: If you're on mac you can also install via `brew install nvm` but I don't know if that will update your shell initialization scripts.